# Finding and linking to the latest commit of a different repository?

Tags: github, github-actions

GitHub has a feature called template repositories. You can mark a repository as a template repository, which then allows you to create a new repository with the template repository as the base. All it does is basically copy the template repository and create a new repository from it.

It's a neat feature, but there is something that bothers me: the new repository essentially combines all the commits of the template repository into one commit - Initial commit. That is the only commit you see in the new repository. There is no way to find out which commit was the latest in the template repository at the time you created the new repository.

I want to fix that using GitHub actions. I already have a workflow that makes changes to the new code (replacing instances of the template project name with the new project name), which is then automatically committed to the new repository. This workflow is triggered whenever a new repository is created - it basically just checks if the current commit is the first commit. Now I want to extend it by also adding the hash and direct link of the latest commit in the template repository, as part of the commit message of the new commit in the new repository.

So in the end, I would have this commit history in the new repository:

- Initial commit (basically the unchanged content from the template repository)
- Rename project, log latest template commit (new line) Latest template commit: (hash with link to latest template repository commit)

How can I do that? Is it possible to get the latest commit from a different repository?

Comment: like https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/commits#list-commits ?

Comment: @rethab I'll be honest, I have no idea what to do with this... I'm still very new with GitHub Actions (probably should've mentioned that) and I only ever used stuff like "actions/checkout@v2". How would I even make use of the API within a workflow file?

Comment: Take a look at github-script: It's an easy way to start using the API from within a workflow. Here's an example: https://github.com/actions/github-script#welcome-a-first-time-contributor

Comment: @rethab I see... that makes more sense to me. Thanks! I'll take a look into it.